# How to convert HTML to text?

Tags: linux, terminal, conversion, html, curl

How it is possible to convert HTML to text file in Linux? For example I want to `curl` a query to Google, then convert the output html to text and read converted text on my terminal. I am using RHEL6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think curl has a built in HTML processor. However:

```
lynx --dump <URL>
```

does the trick.

If you still want to use curl, you could use `html2text` (available in Ubuntu).

Comment: FYI lynx expects/documents a single `-` as option prefix.  Although it'll process a `--` just fine.

Answer (score 8):

You can install `html2text` (an advanced HTML-to-text converter) and the usage is straight forward:

```
$ html2text http://example.com/
$ cat file.html | html2text -o file.txt
```

Install by:

- Linux: `apt-get install html2text`
- OS X: `brew install html2text`

Example with `curl`:

```
$ curl -sL google.com | html2text
Search Images Maps Play YouTube News Gmail Drive More ?
Web History | Settings | Sign in
     A better way to browse the web
       Get Google Chrome

          Advanced search Language tools

        [Google Search][I'm Feeling Lucky]

     Advertising Programmes Business Solutions+GoogleAbout GoogleGoogle.com
                           ? 2016 - Privacy - Terms
```